# Dual boot Windows 8.1 BSOD on startup after resizing partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 beside Windows 8.1 on my laptop with UEFI bios. Everything works fine. One day I wanted to extend my Ubuntu partition:

1. I booted indows, removed some unused files, uninstalled some programs.
2. I shutdown windows and booted an Ubuntu live USB.
3. I resized Windows' partition and then extended the Ubuntu partition.
4. I booted the Ubuntu installation and everything worked fine!

But today I faced a problem mounting the Windows partition. I read about fast startup windows 8.1 feature and tried to launch windows but it shows BSOD on every startup.

I think the problem is that the Windows partition (NTFS) was in "fast startup" mode and I've resized it.

Is there any way to repair "fast startup" mode, or disable it? I really want to launch Windows.

I've tried to remove hiber file with option remove_hiberfile on mount, but receive the error below:

```
root@valery-P50-A-K4M:~# mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /media/valery/win
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

In read only mode the Windows partition works fine.

[This is what I read about fast startup](http://www.unixmen.com/fix-windows-8-dual-boot-ntfs-partition-mount-failure-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue:

I created a bootable Windows 8.1 USB disk on my windows desktop and booted it.

In the repair menu I selected **Advanced Repair Settings > Startup Repair** (maybe not the exact words as I was using a Russian language version)